# Regarding android app coding, specifically to a camera activity

Tags: java, android

My Idea

[image]

I want to ask for advice how to implement this idea of mine to the camera activity I've made.

I tried searching for examples of what I want to do, but it seems what I'm searching isn't hitting the proper words to search so I've been hitting walls in this.

Basically, I'm trying to make an app that takes a picture then labels it so as to be used for machine learning in image recognition.

Please advice me what libraries and commands I can use to do this or even what this function can be called as I'm really a newbie at java and android programming.

```js
package com.example.jeriously.mama;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;


public class CaptureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button getpicture_b;
    Intent getpicture_i, capture_i;
    TextureView getpicture_view_tv;
    String label, labelcontent;
    int xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static{
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0,90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90,0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180,270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270,180);
    }

    private String cameraId;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;

    //Save to FILE
    private File picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8, picture9, picture10;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener1, readerListener2, readerListener3, readerListener4, readerListener5, readerListener6, readerListener7, readerListener8, readerListener9, readerListener10;


    CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice=null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture);

        capture_i = getIntent();
        label = capture_i.getStringExtra(SetupNewActivity.LABEL);

        getpicture_view_tv = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.getpicture_view);
        //From Java 1.4 , you can use keyword 'assert' to check expression true or false
        assert getpicture_view_tv != null;
        getpicture_view_tv.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        getpicture_b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getpicture);
        getpicture_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    private void takePicture() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            return;
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try{
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if(characteristics != null)
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                        .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

            //Capture image with custom size
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            if(jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0)
            {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width,height,ImageFormat.JPEG,1);
            List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
            outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurface.add(new Surface(getpicture_view_tv.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            //Check orientation base on device
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            picture1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+label+"1.jpg");
            readerListener1 = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try{
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);

                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        {
                            if(image != null)
                                image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try{
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(picture1);
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                    }finally {
                        if(outputStream != null)
                            outputStream.close();
                    }
                }

            };
            //txt saving to be converted to xml in RPi
            labelcontent  = "<annotation>\n" +
                    "\t<folder>new</folder>\n" +
                    "\t<filename>"+label+".jpg</filename>\n" +
                    "\t<path>C:\\tensorflow_cards\\test\\"+label+".jpg</path>\n" +
                    "\t<source>\n" +
                    "\t\t<database>Unknown</database>\n" +
                    "\t</source>\n" +
                    "\t<size>\n" +
                    "\t\t<width>"+width+"</width>\n" +
                    "\t\t<height>"+height+"</height>\n" +
                    "\t\t<depth>3</depth>\n" +
                    "\t</size>\n" +
                    "\t<segmented>0</segmented>\n" +
                    "\t<object>\n" +
                    "\t\t<name>"+label+"</name>\n" +
                    "\t\t<pose>Unspecified</pose>\n" +
                    "\t\t<truncated>0</truncated>\n" +
                    "\t\t<difficult>0</difficult>\n" +
                    "\t\t<bndbox>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<xmin>"+xmin+"</xmin>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<ymin>"+ymin+"</ymin>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<xmax>"+xmax+"</xmax>\n" +
                    "\t\t\t<ymax>"+ymax+"</ymax>\n" +
                    "\t\t</bndbox>\n" +
                    "\t</object>\n" +
                    "</annotation>\n";
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(label+".txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
                fileOutputStream.write(labelcontent.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //txt saving to be converted to xml in RPi

            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener10,mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(CaptureActivity.this, "Saved "+label+"1"+".jpg & .txt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    try{
                        cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(),captureListener,mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                }
            },mBackgroundHandler);


        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCameraPreview() {
        try{
            SurfaceTexture texture = getpicture_view_tv.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert  texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(),imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    if(cameraDevice == null)
                        return;
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(CaptureActivity.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try{
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(),null,mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try{
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            //Check realtime permission if run higher API 23
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                },REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId,stateCallback,null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
        {
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can't use camera without permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if(getpicture_view_tv.isAvailable())
            openCamera();
        else
            getpicture_view_tv.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try{
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread= null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/getpicture_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/captureimage"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getpicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/getpicture_capture"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Manifest File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jeriously.mama">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FindActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SetupNewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CommonItemsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MyItemsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CaptureActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PhonesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".KeysActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".WalletsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I

Comment: Can you Show us your Manifest.xml file too pls

Comment: I've added the manifest file. Thanks for the help in the image, I'm a new user at forums so I'm still not used to this kinds of formatting